# How to remove repeated code for ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving the data where a lot of fields are null, and I have to populate something if the field is null.

like in the below data

```
{   //...
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
    // around 200+ fields
 }
```

As here, the transit_depart is null, I'm using the ternary operator to put something in return if the data is null like this ;

```
// this is a reproducible example.
// there are some other styles and comp to display if/else part
{transit_depart ? <>{transit_depart}</> : <>Not Available<>}
```

This is working as expected but the problem is I have around 200+ fields like this and if I follow this then in the future if we have to make any UI change then we will be changing all the relevant code here. So how to avoid it or how can we can manage this.

Comment: You can get the list of keys of the object. `map` them, see if the obj.key is null. If null, return what you need to replace the vale, else, return the same value

Comment: This is one object, having all these types of different fields, how can I map this?

Comment: Getting the keys via object.keys() should get all fields. Accessing obj.key of the list of keys should get all values. Just use comparison after getting the values to see if you need to replace the value or not

Comment: I would strongly warn you against doing blanket fill-ins for all fields. null is useful in that it shows that there is no value set for this key. If you just start filling things in, you may fill in with the wrong data type (for instance a string where a number is required) and you might not be able to determine what fields have "real" values, and which are auto-fill-ins.

Comment: I can see a lot of answers showing map function, like this but what if I have some fields where I don't want to use the same style which will be mapped for all of the fields. ? 
Or say if I want to exclude some of them with this map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing unavailable data with a default value requires a previous analysis. Most probably many fields may have different default values.

For example, `0` for certain amounts; `now` for some dates, but `first day of the year` for others; `" "`, `"TBD"` or `"N/A"` for some strings...

You need a method to map some fields to specific default values for those fields, and a final failover default for the rest of the fields.

For the sample data provided

```
let data = {
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null    
}
```

we might want that `milestatus` default be 0, the `transit_depart` default be the Jan 1st 2021, and all the other fields default to `"N/A"`; we could define a defaults object

```
  {
    milestatus: 0,
    transit_depart: new Date('2021-01-01')
  }
```

and a `setDefaults` function to map the data fields to the defaults

```
function setDefaults(data) {
  const someDefaults = {
    milestatus: 0,
    transit_depart: new Date('2021-01-01')
  }
  const theDefault = "N/A";  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (value==null) {
      if (someDefaults[key]!=null) {
        data[key] = someDefaults[key]
      } else {
        data[key] = theDefault;
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

running the function against the sample data
`setDefaults(data)`

would transform `data` to contain

```
{
  IGM_ETD:"2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00",
  milestatus:0,
  transit_depart:"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  etd_atd:"N/A"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to clean up the code:

```
const incomingData = {
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
};

// Generic function component for field
const Field = ({ data }) => {
    if (isMySpecifcField) {
        return <SpecificFieldComponent />;
    }
    return data ? data : 'Not Available';
};

// rendering the fields

{
    Object.keys(incomingData).map((fieldData) => {
        return <Field data={fieldData} />;
    });
}
```

Comment: Snippet results to error. Kindly check perhaps.

Comment: My bad, it's not a runnable snippet. Aim was to give an idea on how to improve. I've updated  the formatting

Comment: No problme anesh if its not runnig here i got the point , I can see a lot of answers showing map function, like this but what if I have some fields where I don't want to use the same style which will be mapped for all of the fields. ? 
Or say if I want to exclude some of them with this map function?

Comment: You're totally correct about that point. And yes in that case, with my solution would not be possible. But I have done this to address a specific thing mentioned `I have around 200+ fields like this and if I follow this then in the future if we have to make any UI change then we will be changing all the relevant code`. The advantage of using the solution I proposed is that next time you have a UI change, you won't have to go to each one of those 200 fields (generic Ui change ofcourse. something that is applicable to all fields at once)

Comment: Basically when you said `changing all the relevant code`, I assumed that all 200 would need the UI change at the same time.

Comment: @atropabelladona I have updated the code to support specific fields and return custom styled component

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate through your data, checking each value as you go.

```js
var data = {
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
    // around 200+ fields
}

for(let prop in data)
{
  console.log(data[prop] ? `<>${data[prop]}</>` : "<>Not Available<>" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one.

```js
var data = {
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
    // around 200+ fields
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(x => {
  if(!data[x])
     data[x] = '<>Not Available<>'
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say this is our object:

```
let transitData = {   //...
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
    // around 200+ fields
 }
```

Loop through the `values`, check if `null`.  If not `null`, you can access the data like so:

```
return(
   <div>
     {Object.values(transitData).map((value, i) => value === null ? 'Value is Null' : console.log(Object.keys(transitData)[i], value))}
   </div>
)
```

Now, if you want to explicitly style a certain `field`, you need to build a custom check function to do so.  Here is an example of how it may look:

```
const customFieldStyle = (fieldName, value) => {
    if (fieldName === 'milestatus'){
        return <span id={custom_mile_styler}>{value}</span>
    } else {
        // this is where you'll put your default style
        return <span id={default_field_styler}>{value}</span>
    }
}
```

And now, it will look like this in render:

```
return(
   <div>
     {Object.values(transitData).map((value, i) => value === null ? 'Value is Null' : customFieldStyle(Object.keys(transitData)[i], value)}
   </div>
)
```

What that function will do is take ALL the `key/value` pairs that are not `null` and decorate them accordingly.  Simply add more conditionals for explicit field names in the `customFieldStyle` and render whatever type of styling you want using your choice of `CSS` and `JSX`.

Comment: I can see a lot of answers showing map function, like this but what if I have some fields where I don't want to use the same style which will be mapped for all of the fields. ? 
Or say if I want to exclude some of them with this map function?

Comment: At that point, I would make a custom validator explicitly checking for certain fields.  And from there, you can make custom styling for specific fields.  I will show you an example above - give me a few.

Comment: @atropabelladona I put a custom styling function and explained how you would render different results.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an OR statement:

```
<>{transit_depart || 'Not Available'}</>
```

If `transit_depart` is defined, the value will be used. If not, it will use `'Not available'`.

The problem with previous solution is that `0` will be also omitted since its falsy. To avoid this, you can use [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (check if your environment support it):

```
<>{transit_depart ?? 'Not Available'}</>
```

Answer (score 1):

One options it create a function to validate:

```js
const itsAvailable = (value) => {
  return value ?? 'Not Available'
 }
 
console.log(itsAvailable(null)) // will return Not Available

console.log(itsAvailable(34)) // wil return 34
```

And then just map the object like this

```
{ Object.keys(<your object>).map(field=> itsAvailable(<your object>[field]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following

```
const incomingData = {
    IGM_ETD: '2021-11-27T23:59:00+05:00',
    milestatus: null,
    transit_depart: null,
    etd_atd: null,
};

const notAvailableMessage = 'Not Available'

// rendering the fields
function Compoennt() {
    return (
        <div>
           Field 1: {incomingData.field1 || notAvailableMessage}
           Field 2: {incomingData.field2 || notAvailableMessage}
           Field 3: {incomingData.field3 || notAvailableMessage}
        </div>
    )
}
```